# How do I retrieve the post title of a default post in which certain post type posts are fetched and link to it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to display titles of post type posts contributed by guest authors:

```
    function myprefix_custom_grid_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Parse your shortcode settings with it's defaults
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(

        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'term'           => ''
    ), $atts, 'myprefix_custom_grid' );
$user_id = userpro_get_view_user( get_query_var('up_username') );
    // Extract shortcode atributes
    extract( $atts );

    // Define output var
    $output = '';





    // Define query
    $query_args = array(
    'author'=> $user_id,
        'post_type'      => 'items', // Change this to the type of post you want to show
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    );

    // Query by term if defined
    if ( $term ) {

        $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'ID',
                'terms'    => $term,

            ),
        );

    }

    // Query posts
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    // Add content if we found posts via our query
    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {

        // Open div wrapper around loop
        $output .= '<div>';

        // Loop through posts
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {

            // Sets up post data so you can use functions like get_the_title(), get_permalink(), etc
            $custom_query->the_post();

            // This is the output for your entry so what you want to do for each post.
            $output .= '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>';

        }

        // Close div wrapper around loop
        $output .= '</div>';

        // Restore data
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }

    // Return your shortcode output
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'myprefix_custom_grid', 'myprefix_custom_grid_shortcode' );
```

These post type posts are fetched in default posts (this is how I create a directory site) by the following grid filter with a dynamic query (by matching default post titles with post type category names):

```
    function items_query_args($query_args, $grid_name ) {
    if ($grid_name == 'items_grid') {

        $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'itemscategories',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms' => get_post_field( 'post_name' ),
        ),
    );
    $query_args['post_type'] = 'items';

    }

    return $query_args;

}
add_filter('tg_wp_query_args', 'items_query_args', 10, 2);
```

So these post type posts displayed by the grid are fetched within default posts, and the first code only displays the title of these post type posts on the user's profiles, for a reference to see which user contributed with which post type posts.

I would like the first code to be able to display also the title of the default post where the post type post is fetched.

So for example instead of displaying only the
"Post type post title", as it does now, it should display ["Post type post title" IN "Deafult post title"].

How do i modify the first code so that it would detect the deafult post title of the post where the post type post is fetched, so that it would show it in the format specified above and would also link to it?

UPDATE:
I think I will have to settle by displaying the custom taxonomy "itemscategories" names beside the titles, instead of the title of the post where is embedded, since they are identic.
Eventually someone can help to say how to display that instead?